Listening for the output of a subprocess
I'm trying to get the output of a subprocess created using PySide6' QProcess. However the documentation doesn't specify when the readyRead signal is being emmitted. From my tests it seems arbitrary, as even flushing the output in the subprocess or sending lines (ended with the newline character) doesn't work.
I'd like to know how to deterministically read the stdout  of a subprocess with PySide6, if it's even possible.
Here's the minimal code example for the parent process:
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QProcess, QByteArray


class ProcessExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.process = QProcess()
        self.process.readyRead.connect(self.handle_stdout)
        self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.handle_stderr)
        self.process.errorOccurred.connect(self.handle_process_error)
        self.process.stateChanged.connect(self.current_process_state)
        self.process.finished.connect(self.handle_finished)

    
    def start_process(self):
        self.process.start("python", ['test_qprocess_program.py'])
        self.process.waitForStarted()


    def write_to_process(self, message):
        print("No. bytes written: ", self.process.write(message))
        self.process.waitForReadyRead()


    def handle_stdout(self):
        print('u')

    
    def handle_stderr(self):
        error_output: QByteArray = self.process.readAllStandardError()
        print("Standard Error Output:")
        print(error_output)

    
    def current_process_state(self, state):
        print(state)


    def handle_process_error(self, error):
        print('Process error:')
        print(error)


    def handle_finished(self):
        print("End")
        

app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
p = ProcessExample()
p.start_process()
app.exec()

Here's the minimal code example for the child process:
[print(i**2, flush=True) for i in range(10)]

I'm expecting the letter "u" to appear ten times, as the standard output stream is flushed ten times, however it only appears once.

If you're running another Python script in the other process, then it's not QProcess fault, it's just because Python uses buffering (just use python -u). If that's not the case, please provide an appropriate [mre].

I'm indeed running another Python script, however even with python -u it still doesn't work.

This is not a synchronous interface.  Your process is writing those 10 values as fast as possible, and they get flushed to the pipe.  But by the time the original process reads, the pipe buffer is already full and it's able to read the whole thing in one shot, similar to TCP.  If you add a short "sleep" in there, you should see that.

@TimRoberts you're correct. Adding sleep to the child process casued multiple emittions of readyRead signal, and adding processing of the output handle_stdout method caused it to emit less times.

Please provide a [mre]

@eyllanesc It's literally in the post.

remove waitForXXX method,

also read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-disable-output-buffering-in-python/
